# An understanding problem of analytic function

Tags: distribution-theory, analytic-functions

I am reading a textbook of distribution theory.

Here is the definition of test functions: The class of test functions $\mathcal D(\Omega)$ consists of all functions $\varphi(x)$ defined in $\Omega$, vanishing outside a bounded subset of $\Omega$ that stays away from the boundary of $\Omega$, and such that all partial derivatives of all orders of $\varphi$ are continuous.

Since the vanishing requirement, we know there is no analytic function can be in $\mathcal D$ except $\varphi\equiv0$.

Then, the author said, *Thus any formula for $\varphi$ must be given "in piece".*

Why can he conclude this sentence? Can someone help me with understanding this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a somewhat loose statement, because it depends what functions you're allowed to use in such a formula. But typical combinations of analytic functions are again analytic away from singularities, whereas a non-constant test function is not analytic and yet has no singularities in the usual sense.

Comment: @lan Hi lan, sorry for my late reply. From your latter sentence in the comment, what we can conclude is that a non-constant test function can not be expressed as any typical combination of analytic functions. But how can we eliminate the possibility that a non-constant test function can be expressed as certain typical combination of some other functions? Thanks!